# Selenium doesn't scrape tweet ids

Tags: python, selenium, twitter

Imagine you are in this twitter page and you have to take all of its ids! https://twitter.com/search?l=fr&q=%23metoo%20since%3A2017-11-06%20until%3A2017-11-09&src=typd

I am using selenium to scroll down until there are no more left and then save all ids in a list.

Im afraid my for loop doesn't save them though, what am I doing wrong?

```
twitter_ids_filename = 'all_ids.json'
id_selector = '.time a.tweet-timestamp'
tweet_selector = 'li.js-stream-item'
ids = []

for day in range(days):
    d1 = format_day(increment_day(start, 0))
    d2 = format_day(increment_day(start, 1))
    url = form_url(d1, d2)
    print(url)
    print(d1)
    driver.get(url)
    sleep(delay)

try:
    found_tweets = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(tweet_selector)
    increment = 10

    while len(found_tweets) >= increment:
        print('scrolling down to load more tweets')
        driver.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);')
        sleep(delay)
        found_tweets = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(tweet_selector)
        increment += 10

    print('{} tweets found, {} total'.format(len(found_tweets), len(ids)))

    for tweet in found_tweets:
        try:
            id = tweet.find_element_by_css_selector(id_selector).get_attribute('href').split('/')[-1]
            ids.append(id)
        except StaleElementReferenceException as e:
            print('lost element reference', tweet)

except NoSuchElementException:
    print('no tweets on this day')
```

Comment: Why dont you simple scrape the `data-tweed-id`  ? (no much about selenium here, sorry)

Comment: I can certainly try, could you please give me a small example?

Comment: Are you saying I should use beautiful soup?

Comment: No  - I a m looking at the page you linked, hit F12,  see a `<li ..>` that fits your selector, Then I see a `<div ...>` inside the `<li ...>` .. that `<div ...>`has a class of `js-stream-tweet` and lots of attributes. One of the attributes is `data-tweed-id="....."`. Scrape that and youre golden?

Comment: also ... use `ids.append(id.copy())` just to make sure you get a copy not a reference to the one element you are taking from the split.

Comment: THank you so much, Im kinda struggling but I think it just may work

Comment: if it works, delete the questions  ;o) at least if the copy() did solve it - its a VERY common error for pythonian beginners - just read the linked post and remember it - or post your own solution and mark that as answer

Comment: It has not yet worked but I am trying! If it does I will delete it :)

Comment: Ive done id_selector = 'div.data-tweet-id'
and

id = tweet.find_element_by_css_selector(id_selector)
I don't get anything new. I get 
332 tweets found, 0 total
no tweets on this day

(see the exception) 
honestly I am out of ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is that the selector `li.js-stream-item` is a bit too broad and includes unwanted elements. Here is what I get when selecting by `js-stream-item` class:

[image: screenshot]

As you can see, the first element will not contain any `href`s you are looking for. Solve that by restricting your filter:

```
tweet_selector = 'li.js-stream-item:not(.AdaptiveStreamUserGallery)'
```

If I try that out, I get exactly one id per found tweet with your code:

```
scrolling down to load more tweets
23 tweets found, 0 total
INFO:root:    found 23 ids
INFO:root:    next id: 928321203617583104
INFO:root:    next id: 928317626031407104
INFO:root:    next id: 928268761890803712
INFO:root:    next id: 928262618195873793
INFO:root:    next id: 928239024682172416
INFO:root:    next id: 928220156123385856
INFO:root:    next id: 928191036681261057
INFO:root:    next id: 927958439153881088
INFO:root:    next id: 927957292418465793
INFO:root:    next id: 927898097203761153
INFO:root:    next id: 927804540031782912
INFO:root:    next id: 927799255699476481
INFO:root:    next id: 927779606429609984
INFO:root:    next id: 927648294016339970
INFO:root:    next id: 927590257297682432
INFO:root:    next id: 927536130827964416
INFO:root:    next id: 927523922534428672
INFO:root:    next id: 927521799063130113
INFO:root:    next id: 927331391091740672
INFO:root:    next id: 927330842304753664
INFO:root:    next id: 927330365982892033
INFO:root:    next id: 927325770925604865
INFO:root:    next id: 927324960175067137
```

Another hint: your code will always collect only last `n` (where `n` is as in `?q=%n`) tweets because you always overwrite the `found_tweets` list in the loop. You have to aggregate them:

```
found_tweets = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(tweet_selector)
all_tweets = found_tweets[:]
increment = 0

while len(found_tweets) >= increment:
    print('scrolling down to load more tweets')
    driver.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);')
    time.sleep(delay)
    found_tweets = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(tweet_selector)
    all_tweets += found_tweets[:]

    print('{} tweets found, {} total'.format(len(found_tweets), len(ids)))
    increment += 10


for tweet in all_tweets:
    try:
        id = tweet.find_element_by_css_selector(id_selector).get_attribute('href').split('/')[-1]
        ids.append(id)
    except StaleElementReferenceException as e:
        print('lost element reference', tweet)

print(ids)
```

Comment: You sir, are my hero. I see now I suck at scraping. Can you suggest me some good guide?

Comment: @blacksatius Don't put yourself down, those errors are rarely obvious and easy to spot. As for the guides, sorry, nothing in mind! Keep doing what you do and you will get better in no time.

Comment: Okay I am terribly sorry but I have a prob.

            next_tweets_chunk = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(tweet_selector)
            found_tweets += next_tweets_chunk[:]

breaks the loop and if I don't add it, I don't find any ids

Comment: @blacksatius Sorry, my bad - I updated the answer with the complete code sample I used.